# Sum of two i.i.d random variables involving Meijer-G function

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I have two i.i.d random variables $V_1$ and $V_2$ with parameters $\beta,\lambda$. Their PDF is given as $f_{V_1}(v_1)=\frac{1}{\Gamma^2(\beta)}\frac{1}{v_1}G^{2,0}_{0,2}\left(\frac{v_1\lambda^2}{\alpha^2}|\frac{-}{\beta,\beta}\right)$ and $f_{V_2}(v_2)=\frac{1}{\Gamma^2(\beta)}\frac{1}{v_2}G^{2,0}_{0,2}\left(\frac{v_2\lambda^2}{\alpha^2}|\frac{-}{\beta,\beta}\right)$. My doubt is how to add $V_1$ and $V_2$ using convolution approach as it involves Meijer-G function. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do the G functions reduce to more elementary functions? That would be the first thing I would check.

Comment: Those G functions as you have written them are constants. Typo?

Comment: My mistake.....I had corrected it

Comment: Mathematica claims your G-functions reduce to Bessel functions (which may or may not help). For the first G-function you have: $2 \left(\frac{\lambda ^2 v_1}{\text{$\alpha $2}}\right){}^{\beta } K_0\left(2
   \sqrt{\frac{\lambda ^2 v_1}{\text{$\alpha $2}}}\right)$